# exec pdfimages in PHP

Tags: php, exec

I have full root access through VPS (CentOS).

In Unix shell I am able to extract images with following command:

```
pdfimages -j xyz.pdf images
```

But I am unable to execute the command through PHP

```
exec ("pdfimages -j xyz.pdf images");
```

xpdf is installed. Also I have checked that // Exec function exists; // Exec is not disabled; // Safe Mode is not on.. by using following code:

```
$exec_enabled =
   function_exists('exec') &&
   !in_array('exec', array_map('trim', explode(', ', ini_get('disable_functions')))) &&
   strtolower(ini_get('safe_mode')) != 1;
if($exec_enabled) { echo "enabled"; }
```

The following is however getting executed properly:

```
exec("ls -1 *.php", $output);

  foreach ($output as &$tmp){
     echo "<a href=\"$tmp\">$tmp</a><br>";
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? Where is the issue?

Comment: The following code: system('pdfimages -j xyz.pdf images 2>&1'); is giving the following output "sh: pdfimages: command not found"

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path like below , this will save each image in the folder of your PDF.

'image' is just the file name ..

```
$path = 'path/to/your/folder/';

$pdf = $path.'xyz.pdf';

$command = 'pdfimages -j '.$pdf.' '.$path.'image';

exec($command);
```